# Does HAXM, VT-X slow down my computer when the emulator is not running?

Tags: android, memory-management, android-emulator, virtualization, haxm

I am new to Android development and Intel's visualization, and I had a question about the HAXM.

Now I understand that when the emulator is running, the virtualization essentially takes RAM from my computer and allocates to the virtual emulator when the emulator is running. This effectively decreases the RAM my computer has available for itself.

My question is this - I understand this is the case when the emulator is running. However, what happens when the emulator is *not* running? Is the predefined chunk of memory I selected when installing HAXM still carved out of my system, effectively leaving with with lesser RAM? Or does this only happen when the Android emulator is run?

Comment: If the emulator is not running, the memory is not being allocated.  One simple thing you could do for your own re-assurance is bring up your task manager (if on windows) and look at the memory consumption of your system for when the emulator is running and when it is not running.

Answer (score 2):

The Android emulator is based on QEMU, and HAXM is a driver that [plugs into this architecture](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/development-tools/haxm-speeds-up-the-android-emulator.html). When the emulator is not running, the QEMU process is not loaded, and will not consume RAM.

Some parts of QEMU (such as kernel drivers) may still be loaded, consuming some resources, but they will not use the RAM pool that you allocated to the Android VM.